# set/get in a Factory

Tags: angularjs

How can I use a set/get in a Factory. I need to set a value (scope) to the factory so I can $compile. But I can't seem to get the syntax correct or get it working. What wrong with the following?  How can I set the value of PrivateVar to $scope.

I want to call

`format.setVar($scope)`            -  in my controller.

My factory looks like this..

```
pqpApp.factory('format', function ($compile, config) {

    var PrivateVar = {};

    var getVar = function () {
        return PrivateVar
    }

    var setVar = function(value)
    {
        PrivateVar = value;
    }

    return {
        getVar: getVar,
        setVar: setVar
    }


  var formatter = {}

(functions go here)

return formatter;
```

Comment: what is it you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: Did you properly inject your `format` factory into your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question but here you go...

Maybe you are confusing three different concepts: service/factory/provider.

A simple factory can be done like this:

```
myApp.factory('MyFactory', function () {
        var myFactory = {};

        // myProperty
        myFactory.myProperty = 'Hello';

        // Set myProperty
        myFactory.setProperty = function (value) {
            this.myProperty = value;
        };

        return myFactory;
    });
```

Then just inject the factory `MyFactory` in your controller and use:

```
MyFactory.setProperty('World');    // Sets myProperty with value 'World'
$scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;    // Access myProperty value and save it to `$scope.property`
```

Answer (score 1):

If we take your code as is, then you are trying to return two objects from the same factory (the object on line 14 and the formatter on the last line).

In order to get back the `setVar` and `getVar` functions from the factory while keeping `PrivateVar` private, you can write the factory like this:

```js
    pqpApp.factory('format', function ($compile, config) {

        var PrivateVar = {};

        this.getVar = function () {
            return PrivateVar;
        }

        this.setVar = function(value)
        {
            PrivateVar = value;
        }

        return {
            getVar: this.getVar,
            setVar: this.setVar 
        }
        // or could just 'return this;'
}
```

Then you can set `PrivateVar` to whatever you like from the controller i.e.

```js
pqpApp.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, format) {
    format.setVar($scope);
})
```